# HowTo: Logged in only in Chrome, not Google Website?

Tags: google-chrome, google-search, google-sync

I want to use Chrome's built in feature to backup/sync my passwords and bookmarks to my Google account. Therefor I need to login with my GMail account in Chrome, but I don't want to be logged into the "Google Website" (Google Search, GMail, ...) in the browser also.

Is it possible to disable to be automatically logged into the Google website, when I'm logged into Chrome with my Google account and use sync feature?

Comment: In order to log into your account within Chrome, you have to log into your account, this by design logs you into your Google account within your Chrome session.  You would have to not log into your account within Chrome and specifically use an unlinked profile, in order to only manually log into your account within your browsing session.  What you want is not possible with Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, it is not possible.**

Logging in any Google service automatically logs you in all Google services. Among many other examples, it has been discussed [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/e96AmYFV_Pg), regarding different logins for GMail and YouTube.